# Accessing test resources from main package in a maven project

Tags: java

As part of an exercise, I am developing code which will read a file and check if it has floats or not. I already made the code, but I am not sure if I am accessing the file correctly or if there is a better way.

**The app :**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Question1 {
    /* Write a method public ArrayList<Double> readValues(String filename) throws ... that reads a file
     * containing floating-point numbers. Throw appropriate exceptions if the file could not be opened
     * or if some of the inputs are not floating-point numbers.
     */

    private static final String RESOURCE_BASE_PATH = "src/test/resources/";

    //under src/main/ java : java_impatient.chapter4.Question1
    public static List<Double> readValues(String filename) throws IOException {
        ArrayList<Double> values = new ArrayList<>();
        try (BufferedReader fileReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename))) {
            //TODO : Complete this with TDD ?
        }
        return values;
    }

}
```

**The test :**

```
import org.testng.Assert;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.*;

import java.util.List;

public class Question1Test {
    //Some other test code here.

    //under src/test : testjava_impatient.chapter4.Question1Test
    @Test
    public void returnsEmptyListForEmptyFile() throws Exception {
        //Is this the best way to get the full path of a file?
        List<Double> values = Question1.readValues( getFilePath("src/test/resources/chapter4/question1_empty.txt") );
        Assert.assertTrue(values.isEmpty(), "List is not empty as expected!");
    }

    private static String getFilePath(String relativePath){
       File file = new File(RESOURCE_BASE_PATH + relativePath);
       String fullPath = file.getAbsolutePath();
       return fullPath;
    }

}
```

Comment: The question's title is a bit missleading, at first I thougth that you wanted to use something from the test package while running the main build instead of the test build.
If you are just going to run it from the IDE, it wouldnt matter at all, but if this was a .jar running on another folder/machine, the test folder wouldnt be accessible because the main build ignores it.
Here we are not talking about packages/modules, rather runtime components, Question1Test.class can access "question1_empty" the same as Question1.class, because in the test build they are all packaged together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven by default packages ".java" files as ".class" from "src/*/java" and ".*" from "src/*/resources", you don't use "src/*/*" because after compiling it doesn't exist.

Just use the folder structure inside the java and resources folder.

Also don't forget that the files you want to access may be within a running jar, or in a build structure made by an ide.

If you didn't change how resoruces are packaged, to access resource you can use:

```
Class<T> {
    public InputStream getResourceAsStream(String name);
    public URL getResource(String name);
}
```

You can use a relative path or absolute (within the resources folder)

ie:

1. relative "question1_empty.txt" (if both elements where in "chapter4")
2. absolute "chapter4/question1_empty.txt"

Instead of FileReader use InputStreamReader

```
new InputStreamReader(Question1Test.class.getResourceAsStream("question1_empty.txt"));
new InputStreamReader(Question1Test.class.getResource("question1_empty.txt").openStream());
```